# Getting "JavaScript API domain is restricted to..." error after adding domain to LinkedIn Javascript API domain list

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

In the past I have added domains to the Javascript API Domains list for my LinkedIn app and had those domains work with the app without issue. However, I added another domain a couple of days ago and I still get the following error

> JavaScript API Domain is restricted to localhost, first.domain.com, second.domain.com,.....

The error message does not contain the new domain I added. This is confusing because I can see the newly added site in the Javascript API domains list in the administration console for the LinkedIn app.

[image]

Is there anything I'm missing or has something changed with the API regarding this?

Comment: This may sound dumb but have you checked you are pointing the right app?

Comment: I was pointing to the correct app (checking by looking at the app key in the settings page verses the key sent to the browser). It ended up being another issue that was causing my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What was happening is that we were adding the new domain to the Authentication list (in the Authentication tab of the settings page) instead of the JavaScript list. Adding the new domain to the Valid SDK Domains list in the Javascript Settings tab worked as expected.

[image: LinkedIn App Settings page]